# Processing control characters

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

I have a log file which contains a bunch of non visible control characters such as hex \u0003.

I would like to replace this using something like SED, but can't get the first part of the regex to match:

> /s/^E/some_string

I am creating the ^E by pressing CTRL-V CTRL-0 CTRL-3 to create the special character, as read from the 'man ascii' page:

> 003   3     03    ETX

However, nothing matches this control character.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I don't know how you're getting that `^E` (what `Ctrl+0 Ctrl+3` do depend on your terminal emulator and keyboard layout). Character 3 would be `Ctrl+V Ctrl+C`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `tr` command. For example:

To delete the control character:

```
tr -d '\033' < file
```

To replace the control character with another:

```
tr '\033' 'x' < file
```

If you are not sure what the value of the control character is, perform an octal dump and it will print it out:

```
$ cat file
hello
^[
world

$ od -b file    
0000000 150 145 154 154 157 012 033 012 167 157 162 154 144 012
0000016
```

So the value of control character `^[` is `\033`.

Answer (score 2):

This perl one-liner will do the job - beware, it will modify the file:

```
perl -i -pe 's#\x{0003}#some_string#g' /path/to/log/file
```

If you want to replace a number of characters with character codes between a specified range:

```
echo {A..Z} | perl -i -pe 's#[\x{0040}-\x{0047}]#P#g'
P P P P P P P H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

(*echo {A..Z}* produces a string of alphabetic characters in bash)

Comment: And if you don't want to modify the file, just drop the `-i` to use perl as a filter.

Answer (score 2):

This will replace all non-printable characters with a `#`

```
sed 's/[^[:print:]]/#/g' logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want, but if it is to substitute for occurrences of the successive hex bytes 0x00 0x03, this should work:

```
$ echo '0 61 20 00 03 0A' | xxd -r | sed 's/\x00\x03/test/g' 
a test
```